# Cant scale an object, trying to scale a torus but wont change size no matter what

Tags: mesh, transforms

Ive been trying to scale something for a good 10 minutes now, pressed the hotkey and swung my mouse around, nothing changed, used the scaling tool and nothing changed, only way I can even change the size of my object is by using the transform menu and that takes way too much precise things, am I doing anything wrong or is it bugged out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Options* panel on the top right, disable the *Affect Only Locations* option:

[image]